# How to copy files from remote machine (ubuntu) to local machine (windows)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, cygwin, rsync, scp

I would like to know about two ways: `scp` and `rsync` and how exactly they are used to copy files.

I tried doing

```
scp ubuntu@ip-10-124-83-21:/home/* /home/ubuntu/crockonjs-2-hd.mov
```

but it didn't work. Using `rsync`, I get

```
rsync: mkstemp "/home/.crockonjs-2-hd.mov.V1x5F8" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

`crockonjs-2-hd.mov` is on my remote machine and I need to pull it down in home folder. I am using Cygwin under Windows, and it would be awesome if someone could tell me how to use these commands correctly.

Comment: On using rsync, I get rsync: mkstemp "/home/.crockonjs-2-hd.mov.V1x5F8" failed: Permission denied (13)

Comment: Looks like you may have the paths on the remote and local machine messed up. Is `ip-10-124-83-21` the remote machine, `ubuntu` the username there? Also, what is the path to that file on the remote machine?

Comment: Are you sure `/home/ubuntu` exists on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

To copy a file from a remote machine to the local one the commands are:

```
scp <remote-user>@<remote-machine>:<remote-path-to-file> <local-destination>
```

Or

```
rsync <remote-user>@<remote-machine>:<remote-path-to-file> <local-destination>
```

Though I'd use `scp` for that. I can't tell what's what in your example, so that's as specific as I can get.

You can also always check the man pages with:

```
man scp
```

Answer (score 0):

`scp -i <path-to-public-key> <remote-user@remote machine>:<remote-path-to-file> <local-destination>`

For example

`scp -i Downloads/xyz.pem ubuntu@xyz.com:/home/ubuntu/sample.csv Desktop/`